# How to delete contact in android?

Tags: android, contacts

I want to delete user name whose name is Leo. So I am putting delete query as follow

```
    int i = getContentResolver().delete(Contacts.CONTENT_URI, Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME +"= 'Leo'",null);
    System.out.println("rows deleted "+i);
```

> ```
> but it returns "rows deleted 0"
> ```

what is wrong with it.

*Edits :*
The above is not working because the field is read only using `Contacts.CONTENT_URI`
You can see using following URI.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Contacts.html

Comment: Show us the database, or atleast the table.

Comment: is the var contacts set?

Comment: May be the record of user Leo does not exists in db table check this too

Comment: select * from table, Or what ever the code happens to be. and maybe your user was already deleted or it does not return a number of how many affected rows, Please correct me, as i don't use java.

Comment: I am using android database. and contact Leo is present

Comment: If anybody have sample delete query for deleting specific contact. It is also fine for me.

Comment: I have modified question to get attention of user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/SampleSyncAdapter/index.html

In above link I can able to find the solution. I can able to delete contacts completely.

The problem is related to sync adapter.

Answer (score 1):

**To delete selected contacts from the contactDB we could use the following code.**

```
ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
                String where = ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME + " = ? ";
                String[] params = new String[] {nam};

                ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();
                ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newDelete(ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_URI)
                        .withSelection(where, params)
                        .build());
                try {
                    cr.applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
                } catch (RemoteException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (OperationApplicationException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

Comment: Hi @Andro Selva, do you know how to real delete contact? The demo code you show just set deleted column 0 to 1.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you should state in Android manifest permission to `WRITE_CONTACTS`. Look in http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html

Comment: I am putting WRITE_CONTACTS this permission in menifest file. If i wont write WRITE_CONTACTS this permission it will give me error. Is it?

Comment: dunno, never tried :) Did you consider instead of '=' use like '%Leo%'